# Can Excel automatically convert an entry into a clickable link inside the same workbook?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

Please let me better clarify my question. What I would like to do is the following:
1)  Have a workbook with, say, 100 worksheets
2)  Each worksheet has a different tab name
3)  Each worksheet contains a range of cells, where I will type entries which may or may not be the tab name of another worksheet
4)  If I happen to enter the tab name of one of these worksheets in any cell, on any worksheet, this name gets automatically hyperlinked to that worksheet, so that by clicking this cell I’ll get redirected to that worksheet. In this destination worksheet I can do the same with the cells and get redirected to another worksheet, and so on, hopping from one worksheet to another.

Any idea on how to set up a range of cells this way?

I know Excel automatically creates Internet hyperlinks when a cell entry begins with "http://" or "www." Can it also be done when the destination is in the same document rather than on the web?

The closest solution I was able to find is this formula, entered i.e. in cell C3:

=IF(A3="P",HYPERLINK("[Test.xlsx]Production!D2","NEXT >>>"),HYPERLINK("[Test.xlsx]Supply!D2","NEXT >>>"))

If the value in cell A3 = P, and I click the hyperlink in cell C3, it will take me to cell D2 of Production worksheet. For any other value in A3, it will take me to cell D2 of Supply worksheet.

But this is still not what I’m looking for. I would like in my case being able to enter “Production” in A3, be converted in a clickable link as it’s the name of a worksheet, and being redirected to Production worksheet when I click on A3, not on other cells.

I looked into IF formulas, but they cannot perform any action other than calculate, copy values, etc. So I suppose my only option is using VBA, which unfortunately is not my forte.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I do believe that VBA Codes are the best way to solve your problem.

Now let me tell you how to use this code.

This can be used as **Worksheet_Change** or **CommandButton_Click**, **Event**
or even **as a Macro**.

Now what would better to do is, in the Worksheet in few BLANK CELLS enter the Sheet Names, *in my example Cell address is A2 downwards*. According to the *"Event of the Code"* VBA will convert them into Hyperlinks.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
      With Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 2 To .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("A" & i), Address:="", _
           SubAddress:="'" & .Range("A" & i).Value & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:=.Range("A" & i).Value
          Next i
        End With
  End Sub
```

**NB: Check the 4th Row of the Code is, For i = 2 To .Range("A" & .Rows,,,**

This 2 is the Row Number & A Column Name means Cell A2 is the First Cell from where downwards the Specified Area begins. You can modify this as you need.

Also my suggestion is, first use the Code as Command Button Click event.

Hope this help you.

**Note,** *this code was tested by me before I've posted it as the Solution.*

Answer (score -1):

**Note,** *adding these rows as ANSWER to help the OP, on his suggestion.*

**Follow these steps to finish the job.**

1. Go to blank sheet, in Cell A2 & A3 write your Sheet name like Sheet1, Sheet2.
2. Hit Developer Tab, find Design Mode, click it.
3. Left to it is Insert, click it and select command button and draw it anywhere in blank area of the  Sheet.
4. Double click the drawn Command Button, Excel will open VBA Editor.
5. You find CommandButton1_Click() and End Sub rows.
6. In between Copy and Paste the Code. *Remember start Copy from like 2 and finish with line 8.*
7. Close VBA editor Window and click the Design button again, it will normal.
8. Finally Click the Command Button.

*You find the Sheet Names in A2 & A3 turn to Hyperlink.*

**NB:** From Cell A2 downwards you can write as many Sheet Names in the Column.

Comment: Now it works like a charm, thank you very much! I actually needed a Range of cells to get hyperlinked rather than just Column A, but I've fixed that by creating a different Command_button for each column, then placing all the buttons outside the visible range of cells to save working space.

Comment: Yoy need to do few modification, Add Dim j as long. Then modify the row 4 to 6 like,,  .Range("A" & i & ":B" & j). This will cover both Column A & B. If unable to crack it ,, then do it the way you are doing New Button for other Columns.

Comment: Write your concern,, Y this has been down voted since OP has written in comments above that, **Now it works like a charm, thank you very much!**  !!

Comment: @design95,, glad to hear that it's working properly,,, now you may accept it as answer,, will help others too, as you can find it's unnecessarily down voted !!